# Is it possible to validate image width, height with vuetify rules?

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

I want to validate image width and height with vuetify. I 've written a fuction to check image and compare with condition. Although I can check width, height of a image, rule allways error

```
                        <v-file-input 
                            :id="'file-input-' + label"
                            ref="fileInput"
                            :rules="rules.minResolution"
                            class="file-input-upload pt-0 pb-2"
                            prepend-icon=""
                            :error-messages="errorMessages"
                            @change="onChange"
                        >
                            <template #message="{ message }">
                                {{ showMessages($t(message), $t(label), maxSize) }}
                            </template>
                            <template v-if="imageError !== ''">
                                {{ $t(imageError) }}
                            </template>
                        </v-file-input>
```

This is export fuction

```
export function minResolution(width, height, error) {
  return file => ( file && (new File(file, width, height) === true)) || error
}
```

```
function File(file, width , height) {
  const reader = new FileReader() 
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = evt => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      if (img.width >= width && img.height >= height) {
        alert(1)
        return true;
      }
    }
    img.src = evt.target.result;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Sorry my english so bad

Comment: u call your `File` function as a class, but it has no constructor and makes also no sense to create for that check a class... next thing: you should handle it async. here you return always false. those are js basics

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your `minResolution` could be async, but it is the only way, with an async validation

```js
export async function minResolution(width, height, error) {
  return file => ( file && (await check_image_dimensions(file, width, height) === true)) || error
}
```

```js
function check_image_dimensions(file, width , height) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.onload = evt => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
        resolve(img.width >= width && img.height >= height);
      }
      img.src = evt.target.result;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: it really return true or false but when it return false the image still upload. unless it pass validate conditon, it wont be upload. sr I dont know how to mention u

Comment: you can't return multiple times. you return always false and try to return true after the check is passed, but there you have already returned false. so you have to handle it async like my example

Comment: to handle async rules, I think you have to try this: https://github.com/abemscac/vuetify-async-validation